# Dynamic content in SharePoint Workflow Email

Tags: workflow, email, alert

i've got a Workflow which starts when a specific column has been updated. It basically just sends an Email to the requester. Quite straighforward.

Im struggling to insert a dynamic text inside the mail. The content of the Mail should be different. Whether an another column has value A or B.

Like if the list item has a column RequestType with value Mobile.

Then the Email would look like this. Please consider only the introduction is different. The rest of the Email is identical:

> Hallo Dear sender,
>
> thanks for your **mobile** request. Custom text for mobile.
>
> Disclaimer text.

Otherwise:

> Hallo Dear sender,
>
> thanks for your **PC** request. Custom text for desktop.
>
> Disclaimer text.

Im am able to do that with SharePoint Designer using an If-statement. But it would be nicer if i could use the If-statement inside the Email in order to avoid creating two send mails actions. And it is actually quite hard to customize the Email using SharePoint Designer due its annoying look and feel.

Does anyone knows a better solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your workflow, you'd want to create a block that is If field equals PC then build a dynamic string of Thanks for your PC request else build a dynamic string thanks for your mobile request. Make sure both actions use the same output variable. Then in your email action, you insert the variable from the dynamic string operation. This will allow you to create any specific text blocks in your email body.

If all you need is simply the values of PC and Mobile, then in the email body, click the button to Add or Change lookup to insert the field.

Comment: My gosh. That was actually easy. I always forget that dynamic string thingy :) Many thanks!

Comment: Any time! You can take it another direction too in that the content could be stored in a list so its easily maintainable (email text can be modified at any time without republishing the workflow) and then based on what the user selected, lookup that information and merge it in.